# How to create alias that contains shell commands

Tags: bash, shell, command, alias

How do I create an alias called 'cpu' that runs this shell command
`sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string`?

I used:

`alias cpu = sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string`

All i get returned is the following:

```
-bash: alias: cpu: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: sysctl: not found
-bash: alias: -n: not found
-bash: alias: machdep.cpu.brand_string: not found
```

Comment: Do not do this.  Seriously, aliases have been obsolete for years.  Write a function: `cpu() { sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string; }`

Comment: Whats wrong with aliases? and are you suggesting to create a myscript.sh file containing a function defined as cpu() that contains sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string? and then calling myscript.sh cpu?

Comment: No, you define the function in your .bashrc or wherever you would be defining the alias.  The trouble with aliases is that they are inflexible, and do not provide any benefit over a function.  To quote from the bash man page: "The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat confusing...For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions"

Comment: thanks, that works nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the spaces around `=` and surround the command with quote.

`alias cpu='sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string'`